# Localhost on windows 7 configuration issue

Tags: windows, iis-7, localhost

When I am making changes on my localhost, it is not working. I am on windows 7 but when I copy the file in which the changes were made, and try to execute them in Windows XP, its working. I as I asked someone who has a lot of knowledge on this and they said it is a configuration issue.

Someone else told me it was because of output caching, so I disabled everything and tried, even then there was no response. Can anyone tell me how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

This was because of caching issue.
Navigate to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\IIS Configuration Manager, select Output caching, then add new rule with follow parameters:
Insert types of files, you are changing(.aspx,.php) in File name extension field and simply unselect all types of caching. Then restart server and it should work now

Comment: I tried it out but doesn't seem to work. (Although I just restarted my system instead of restarting the server because I don't have the auth to do that)

Answer (score 0):

I could hardly understand your word, so I think your very first task is to make sure you understand IIS and how to start troubleshooting.

Without a clearer description on the problem, nobody can provide you useful information on how to resolve it.

If you like, open a support case with Microsoft support team and talk to the support engineer about your issue.

http://support.microsoft.com